# Application Insights Duplicate Request Operation Logs

Tags: azure, .net-core, asp.net-web-api2, azure-application-insights, azure-api-management

Currently in Application Insights we're experiencing 2 very odd issues.
Our infrastructure uses API Management and the backend is Azure App Service with several virtual applications.

We're using NET 6 Web API with Application Insights SDK integration.

The issues are as follows:

1. For all requests to the API, we're getting 1 Request Log from API management and 1 from App Service
2. For both Request logs, dependent calls to other APIs via HTTP Client are not being tracked as dependencies and appropriately associated

The interesting thing is, when we view one of the dependent calls (which are logged as a separate request), it appropriately shows the correlated telemetry.

API Management has Application Insights integration enabled with the correlation mode set to W3C.

To register the telemetry client in DI we do the following:

```
public static IServiceCollection RegisterAppInsightsTelemetry(
    this IServiceCollection serviceCollection,
    Action<ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions>? modifyOptions = null)
{
    serviceCollection.AddOptions<ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions>()
        .Configure<IConfiguration>((settings, configuration) =>
            configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights").Bind(settings));
       
    using var provider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    var options = provider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions>>();

    modifyOptions?.Invoke(options.Value);
       
    serviceCollection.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(options.Value);
    return serviceCollection;
}
```

`ApplicationInsights` config looks like the following, we also explicitly disable AdaptiveSampling in the code:

```
"ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString":"XXXXXX"
}
```

```
builder.Services.RegisterAppInsightsTelemetry(options =>
        {
            options.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;
        });
```

Within our internal Services, our HTTP Clients inject the header `traceparent` with the value set to the current OperationId:

```
public abstract class HttpService<T> : IHttpService where T : HttpClientConfiguration
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly IIdentityAccessor _identityAccessor;
    private readonly HttpClientConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IServiceAccountResolver _serviceAccountResolver;

    protected HttpService(
        HttpClient httpClient,
        IIdentityAccessor identityAccessor,
        IOptions<T> options)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpClient));
        _identityAccessor = identityAccessor;
        _serviceAccountResolver = serviceAccountResolver ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceAccountResolver));
        _configuration = options?.Value ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));

        InjectHeaders(identityAccessor.CurrentTelemetryId);
    }

    private void InjectHeaders(string telemetryId)
    {
        const string traceParentHeader = "traceparent";
        if (_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Contains(traceParentHeader)) 
            return;
        
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(telemetryId))
        {
            telemetryId = Activity.Current?.Id;
        }

        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(traceParentHeader, telemetryId);
    }
}
```

We recently switched from Azure Functions to App Service, we didn't experience these issues on Azure functions so i'm assuming the issue is in how we're registering the app insights SDK.

We've tried manually adding the traceparent header and several variations of settings when registering the SDK on each API.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please share your configuration settings.

Comment: Thanks @Harshitha, Updated the question with redacted configs